# MongoDB - How to replace url in field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have data as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64f029e54cfd5850f6c1a30f"), "pendek" : "test_123_456", "panjang" : "working tester mongodb", "landing_page" : "https://tester.com/", "user_page" : "https://iamold.web.app\n", "web_saya" : "https://yoootester.web.app" }
```

How to replace "iamold.web.app" with "iamnew.web.app"?

I am trying with this code not working:

```
db.web_saya.updateMany(
  { "user_page": { $regex: /iamold/ } },
  { $set: { "user_page": { $regexReplace: { input: "$user_page", find: /iamold/, replacement: "iamnew" } } } }
)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that the `$regexReplace` operator is valid. Probably you mean [`$replaceOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne) operator. Note that it is an operator for the aggregation pipeline. You need the [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) in order to use it.

Note that this will replace the first found "iamold" word. In case you want to replace all the matching words, you should look for [`$replaceAll`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/) operator.

If you know the data pattern in which the `user_page` with "https://iamold.web.app\n" value needed to be updated, would recommend directly updating the value without regex.

```
db.web_saya.updateMany({
  "user_page": {
    $regex: "iamold"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "user_page": {
        $replaceOne: {
          input: "$user_page",
          find: "iamold",
          replacement: "iamnew"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or provide the value with domain URL will be more accurate.

```
db.web_saya.updateMany({
  "user_page": {
    $regex: "https://iamold.web.app"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "user_page": {
        $replaceOne: {
          input: "$user_page",
          find: "https://iamold.web.app",
          replacement: "https://iamnew.web.app"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-AvOZOFsTPp)